# Radio buttons not lining up horizontally

Tags: html, css

My HTML radio buttons are lining up vertically not horizontally. Also, the text for each of them is not right beside the button like I wish it would be.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Payment Method</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="bill"/>
    <label for="bill">Bill Me</label>
    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="credit" checked/>
    <label for="credit">Credit Card</label>
    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="paypal"/>
    <label for="paypal">Paypal</label>  
</fieldset>
```

That is the code for my HTML buttons. I have an external style sheet, but I have not implemented any styling for the buttons as of now.

Comment: What CSS are you using? It is fine without CSS.. http://jsfiddle.net/KvPCp/ Either remove some formatting, or apply `display:inline-block` to the checkboxes.

Comment: I have not implemented any CSS for these radio buttons.  I want them to line up horizontally, but for me they are lining up vertically

Comment: There must be some CSS, as they are horizontally aligned in the example (default).. can you provide an example?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vPRF8AN.jpg

That's how it is on my end

Comment: I want it to look like:

http://i.imgur.com/GPNaGBq.jpg

Answer (score 7):

Checkboxes are aligned horizontally by default, as are the labels. You must be setting `display:block` on an element. Either remove that, or overwrite it by applying `display:inline-block`.

Try the following CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:inline-block;
}

label {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

As I said, these are default properties. You should receive the following results. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KvPCp/) It would be better just to remove `display:block` as opposed to merely overwriting it.