# Centering form fields

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center and align all of my form fields to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9RJe.jpg)

Here my jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/he7Xc/

```
.
```

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284874/radio-buttons-not-lining-up-horizontally

Comment: You're probably going to need to post some more code. Like... what is `.info`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float a div to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740587/float-a-div-to-center)

Comment: post code or share us the link to what you have done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.info {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
}
```

Or you can wrap the field in a `<div>` that has a style of `text-align:center`.

Comment: That centers the text, but it does not align the boxes

Comment: Could you create a Fiddle? I need to see this.

Comment: If it helps, please vote it up or accept, just in case anyone else sees this.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this fiddle i have edited its exactly what you want....

```
<label for="E-mail">E-mail:</label><input type="email" name="email" autofocus required><br>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VwaZJ/